# how can I get the value of Entry Widget when the related class is called after login class

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a login window. I found a good example code here in Stackoverflow and added it with a simple code using Entry widget. After log in successfully, however, I can't get correct values of textvariable of Entry Widget even though I try to get them with Entry's instance.get().
I've tried many ways I could do. But, I can't find what's wrong. 
I'm working with python 2.7. please help.

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkMessageBox as tm

    class LoginFrame:
          def __init__(self):
                root = Tk()


                self.label_1 = Label(root, text="Username")
                self.label_2 = Label(root, text="Password")

                self.entry_1 = Entry(root)
                self.entry_2 = Entry(root, show="*")

                self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
                self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
                self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
                self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

                self.checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Keep me logged in")
                self.checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)

                self.logbtn = Button(root, text="Login", command = 
                                            self._login_btn_clickked)
                self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

                root.mainloop()

          def _login_btn_clickked(self):
                username = self.entry_1.get()
                password = self.entry_2.get()

                #print(username, password)

          if username == "1" and password == "1":
              #tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome John")
              app = EntrySample()
              app.window.mainloop()

          else:
              tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")


  class EntrySample:
          def __init__(self):
               self.window = Tk()
              self.window.title("Test Entry") 

              Label(self.window, text = "Kor").grid(row = 1,
                    column = 1, sticky = W)

              self.kor = IntVar()
              self.enKor = Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.kor,
                    justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

              Label(self.window, text = "Eng").grid(row = 2,
                    column = 1, sticky = W)


              self.eng = IntVar()
              self.enEng = Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.eng,
                    justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

              Label(self.window, text = "Math").grid(row = 3,
                    column = 1, sticky = W)

              self.math = IntVar()
              self.enMath = Entry(self.window, textvariable = self.math,
                    justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 3, column = 2)

              btComputePayment = Button(self.window, text = "Calculate",
                    command = self.compute).grid(
                            row = 4, column = 2, sticky = E)


          def compute(self):
              total = self.kor.get()+self.eng.get()+self.math.get()
              avg = total/3.0
              print total
              print '%3.2f' %avg


  LoginFrame()
```

Comment: add extra 4 spaces before every line of code to correctly format it on SO.

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal ? Add full message in question (as text, not screenshot)

Comment: tkinter can have only one main window (created by `Tk()`). To create subwindow (ie. dialog window) use `tk.Toplevel`. To create new main window you have to `destroy()` previous main window.

Comment: Thanks furas. I'd already tried to use destroy(), quit(), withdraw(). But, I sitll have the same problem. I don't have any error messages. But, the result I have is 0 and 0.00

Comment: btw. you can have only one `Tk()` and only one `mainloop()`

Comment: When I use destroy(), I got the following error message.                                                          Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python2732\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Python2732/harry/test1.py", line 32, in _login_btn_clickked
    self.root.distroy()
  File "C:\Python2732\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1826, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: distroy

Comment: you have typo - `distroy` - it has to be `destroy`

Comment: OMG! I've spent a lot of hours just to find spelliing mistake. Actually, I was  coding again line by line and it worked just before I read your comment. New one worked. But, the old one didn't work. After reading your comment, I found what my mistake was. Now two codes works well. I don't know why God gives me this hard time. Thank furas for your concern. It inspired me to keep on checking my code. It helped a lot.Have a good day!!!